# typedef syntax with struct definition

Tags: c, typedef

I have a sample code for a microcontroller.

There is a structure `typedef`d as shown below.

```
typedef struct _AT91S_SYS {
    AT91_REG     AIC_SMR[32];   // Source Mode Register
    AT91_REG     AIC_SVR[32];   // Source Vector Register
    AT91_REG     AIC_IVR;   // IRQ Vector Register
    ...
} AT91S_SYS, *AT91PS_SYS;
```

I have used `typedef` with structs like `} AT91S_SYS;`.

What does this additional part does? `*AT91PS_SYS;` in `} AT91S_SYS, *AT91PS_SYS;`
Is it a pointer to the `struct _AT91S_SYS` type?

`AT91_REG` is a `typedef` of `volatile unsigned int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the syntax is equivalent to this:

```
typedef struct _AT91S_SYS AT91S_SYS;
typedef struct _AT91S_SYS *AT91PS_SYS;
```

So `AT91PS_SYS` is a pointer type of `AT91S_SYS`.

Answer (score 3):

This just defines the type `AT91PS_SYS` as a pointer to `AT91S_SYS`.

---

The easiest way to understand `typedef`, by the way, is to read the rest of the declaration as if it were just a variable declaration. But, instead of defining variables, you're defining types using whatever type the variable *would* have had.

So, for example,

```
int x, *y, z[5];
```

defines three variables, `int x`, `int *y` and `int z[5]`.

Therefore,

```
typedef int x, *y, z[5];
```

defines two types, `x == int`, `y == int *` and `z == int[5]`. Simple!